# Why the CDB debugger always crashed when I set breakpoints to debug in QtCreator?

Tags: qt, debugging, cdb

My Qt version is :qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64-5.8.0.

The codes run well in release/debug mode, but I cannot debug when some breakpoints set.

I struggled for several hours but still cannot figure out why the cdb always terminated...

Please help me.Thank you!

The useful debugger outputs:

```
15:38:01.638 [711ms]
Breakpoint 103700 hit
15:38:01.638
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for 
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL - 
15:38:01.638
 >  373:        if (getLData(veloData, 1, startTime))
15:38:01.638
onlineprocessing!map+0x290:
15:38:01.638
373 00007ff6`c39be5c0 c744246801000000 mov     dword ptr [rsp+68h],1 
ss:000000a7`eabfe208=00000000
15:38:01.638
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for 
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll - 
15:38:01.638
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for 
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120D.dll - 
15:38:01.638
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for 
C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll - 
15:38:01.642 [4ms]
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for D:\onlineprocessing\build-
onlineprocessing-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2013_64bit-
Debug\debug\opencv_highgui249d.dll

15:38:01.642  
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted    to 

export symbols for    D:\onlineprocessing\build-onlineprocessing-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\opencv_highgui249d.dll
       -  
15:38:01.695 [53ms] sStopped at breakpoint 37 (37) in thread 7. 15:38:01.695

NOTE: INFERIOR SPONTANEOUS STOP
15:38:01.695
Stopped.
15:38:01.695
State changed from InferiorRunOk(11) to InferiorStopOk(14) [master]
15:38:01.700 [5ms]
Checking for wow64 subsystem...
15:38:01.701 [1ms]
<lm m wow64
15:38:01.782 [1ms]
ERROR: Process crashed
15:38:01.782
CDB PROCESS FINISHED, status 1, exit code -2147024866
15:38:01.782
NOTE: ENGINE ILL ******
15:38:01.782
FORWARDING STATE TO InferiorShutdownFailed
15:38:01.782
State changed BY FORCE from InferiorStopOk(14) to InferiorShutdownFailed(17) [master]
15:38:01.783 [1ms]
State changed from InferiorShutdownFailed(17) to EngineShutdownRequested(19) [master]
15:38:01.783
QUEUE: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
15:38:01.863 [80ms]
CALL: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
15:38:01.863
NOTE: ENGINE SHUTDOWN OK
15:38:01.864 [1ms]
State changed from EngineShutdownRequested(19) to EngineShutdownOk(21) [master]
15:38:01.866 [2ms]
State changed from EngineShutdownOk(21) to DebuggerFinished(22) [master]
15:38:01.866
QUEUE: FINISH DEBUGGER
15:38:01.907 [41ms]
NOTE: FINISH DEBUGGER
15:38:01.908 [1ms]
HANDLE RUNCONTROL FINISHED
15:38:01.908
Debugger finished.
```

Comment: Are you using the 32bit or 64bit cdb? Try both is my first advice.

Comment: I use the x64 version Qt5.8.0.

Comment: And I deleted the *.user file and tried to re-configure the project, it works!